# Is this a typo in my copy of The Hunchback of Notre Dame?

Tags: french-language, textual-history, victor-hugo, misprint, the-hunchback-of-notre-dame

> Nevertheless, as be harangued them, the satisfaction and admiration unanimously excited by his costume were dissipated by his words;

Hugo, Victor. The Hunchback of Notre-Dame (AmazonClassics Edition) (p. 29). AmazonClassics. Kindle Edition.

Is the above sentence a typo? In every version of the book I look at, oddly enough including my physical copy, they have this same text.

Comment: Nice question! I'm now reading *Notre Dame de Paris*, the original book in French.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is an obvious typo, *be* for *he*. The [original](https://archive.org/details/bnf-bpt6k6497134z/page/n45/mode/2up) has:

> Cependant, tandis qu’il haranguait, la satisfaction, l’admiration unanimement excitées par son costume, se dissipaient à ses paroles;

*il haranguait* translates to *he was haranguing*. Why every edition you've seen of the 1888 [Isabel Florence Hapgood translation](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2610/pg2610-images.html) has this typo, I don't know. Presumably all of them derive from a typo in either one of the printed editions of this text, or (more likely) an uncorrected scanning error while digitizing the text. Digitized texts are often very poorly proofread.

Other editions translate this sentence differently. From a couple of anonymous translations:

> While he was speaking, however, the universal satisfaction, nay, admiration, excited by his costume, was dispelled by his words. ([Chapman and Hall edition](https://archive.org/details/354466269.2253.emory.edu/page/n21/mode/2up), 1877)
>
> Unfortunately, the admiration and satisfaction so universally excited by his costume died out during his harangue. ([Harvard Classics edition](https://www.bartleby.com/lit-hub/notre-dame-de-paris/ii-pierre-gringoire), 1917)

Comment: The typo originated in [the Project Gutenberg edition](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2610/pg2610-images.html#link2HCH0002) of the novel. Project Gutenberg editions start with OCR, the output of which is then corrected by volunteer proof-readers. It is easy to submit errata following the [process here](https://www.gutenberg.org/help/errata.html).

Comment: I know nothing about the subject matter. but I am an experienced and generally competent user of mother English (NZ-British version :-). To me the originally queried passage and eg the two examples you give seem to be equivalnt to the original. What am I missing.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: The version in the question starts “As **be** harangued them…”  The typo is so blatant that my brain silently autocorrected it, and I had to re-read several times to find it — I guess you missed it for the same reason…

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine :-) :-) :-) :-( !!! - Thanks. I was so busy looking at the construction that I missed the small elephant in the room.

Comment: @GarethRees I expected this would require attribution to Project Gutenberg, but [that's not the opinion of the Project](https://www.gutenberg.org/help/no_sweat_copyright.html).

Comment: I submitted an erratum and the typo is now fixed in the Project Gutenberg edition.

Comment: @GarethRees Excellent efficiency!

Comment: @GarethRees What's even weirder is my book is printed by a UK-based Publishing company. I emailed them so that they can fix it in future prints.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Do you mean that Gareth is efficiently excellent in reporting the typo, or that Project Gutenberg is excellently efficient at fixing it once reported? Inquiring minds wanna know

Comment: @verbose Both things - my comment was similarly efficient  ;)